# Floyd–Steinberg dithering with compositor nodes

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I can't get Floyd-Steinberg dithering work in compositor nodes.
I know there is a dithering option inside blender, but for some artistic effects I want to do later with this effect, I need it as nodes in the compositor.

Any ideas?

### [image: Floyd–Steinberg dithering try blender]

EDIT:
Current look with faking it.
Real FSD is probably not possible. Right?
[image: floyd steinberg dithering]
[image]

Comment: I think it is not possible because of FSD is an sequential funktion reusing each modified pixel.
Now I'm trying to fake it...

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4570/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QesQ5.jpg