# How do you Render With Gamma-Aware Floyd-Steinberg Dithering in Blender?

Tags: rendering

Can someone please answer this question?

I was trying to render something in Blender, and Blender used the default dithering algorithm in Blender.

Here are the Blender post processing settings:[image: The Blender post processing settings include the dither strength.]

That dithering is not [Floyd-Steinberg dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering).

How do I make Blender render with [Gamma-aware](https://www.nayuki.io/page/gamma-aware-image-dithering) Floyd-Steinberg dithering instead?

Also, if I make Blender render an animation with error diffusion dithering, it should be like the Floyd-Steinberg for still images, except it should diffuse the error through space *and* time.

I am asking about using Floyd-Steinberg dithering, which is not [Ordered dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_dithering), like in [this article](https://bradeneliason.com/non-photorealistic-rendering-dithering/)

On a comment on [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101514/floyd-steinberg-dithering-with-compositor-nodes), someone said they do not think that is possible to do Floyd-Steinberg dithering using using compositor nodes.

Is there some way to do Floyd-Steinberg dithering that does not use compositor nodes?

Comment: what do u mean by *in the viewport*? and why would u want that? i could understand if u would maybe want to dither the rendered output through *compositor* nodes

Comment: This question is understandable if you know about [Domain Coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) and [Floyd-Steinberg Dithering])(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering).  Perhaps [this article](https://bradeneliason.com/non-photorealistic-rendering-dithering/) will help the OP solve the problem. -- You need to set up compositor nodes to implement the dithering algorithm of your choice.

Comment: @Marty Fouts Okay, I finished reading the article many days ago.